# Convert private fields to constants

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea

I have a badly designed class from other developer as follows:

```
public class Clz {
    private String SUPPOSED_TO_BE_CONSTANT_1 = "value 1";
    private String SUPPOSED_TO_BE_CONSTANT_2 = "value 2";
    private String SUPPOSED_TO_BE_CONSTANT_3 = "value 3";
    //... And many more
}
```

I need these fields to be, `private static final FIELD;`. How can achieve the same in an automated manner?

I have tried,

- Extracting constant
- Changing signature

but nothing works.

**Note:** I am using  Intellij Idea/Android Studio IDE

Comment: *but nothing works.* - what do you mean?

Comment: Does setting `private static final String SUPPOSED_TO_BE_CONSTANT_1;` not work, or what?

Comment: @GauravMall : Edited -- would like to do it in an automated way

Comment: Meaning you want to automatically generate these fields, by using an option in the IDE or programmatically?

Comment: @GauravMall private static final String SUPPOSED_TO_BE_CONSTANT_1; won't work as it will generate compilation error :-)

Comment: @GauravMall : Yes, I would like to convert these fields to the desired syntax in an automated way(plugin/IDE option, etc.)

Comment: @pulp_fiction what do you mean by nothing works?

Comment: @Kris : Fair enough. I had missed out the values.

Comment: @Kris How would it generate a compilation error. I create variables like these all the time. They are recommended by Google.

Comment: Use IDE find and replace function? ex find "private " and replace with "private final" suffice?

Comment: @GauravMall Its a simple mistake pulp_fiction corrected in question. btw, private static final String SUPPOSED_TO_BE_CONSTANT_1;  will give you a compiler error "The blank final field SUPPOSED_TO_BE_CONSTANT_1 may not have been initialized". Initialization is must for final variables static or not.

Comment: @Kris Oh yes, I supposed that pulp_fiction took care of that. Didn't know that he left his fields empty :)

Comment: @pulp_fiction if all variables are having a common prefix and data type a simple find & replace will do :-) Not sure that is the case

Comment: To make the fields final use the IntelliJ IDEA inspection "Field may be 'final'" (Java | Code style issues | Field may be 'final'). To apply the fix for all the fields press _Alt+Enter_ at one of them, press right arrow at suggestion to make the field final, apply "fix all 'field may be final' problems in file". After making fields final, use "Field may be 'static'" inspection the same way (Java | Performance | Field may be 'static').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i got this right (including content from comments), you would like to replace all `private String SUPPOSED_TO_BE_CONSTANT` with `private static final String SUPPOSED_TO_BE_CONSTANT`. I am not aware if `Intellij-IDEA` is capable of such thing, but you can always use a notepad for this (I use `Notepad++`) and replace them with a regex.

The regex to find the fields that should be changed is: `private String ([A-Z]\w+)` (Note the A-Z part. It is there to catch only the supposed `static final` fields which start with an uppercase).

Then replace it with `private static final String \1`

The result in `Notepad++` (`Ctrl+H` menu) is from:

```
private String SUPPOSED_TO_BE_CONSTANT_1 = "value 1";
private String SUPPOSED_TO_BE_CONSTANT_2 = "value 2";
private String SUPPOSED_TO_BE_CONSTANT_3 = "value 3";
```

to:

```
private static final String SUPPOSED_TO_BE_CONSTANT_1 = "value 1";
private static final String SUPPOSED_TO_BE_CONSTANT_2 = "value 2";
private static final String SUPPOSED_TO_BE_CONSTANT_3 = "value 3";
```

Most likely, you will replace variables that you don't want to replace but you can always adjust the regex to fit in your case.

Comment: Yes, I did something similar

Comment: Why do you use ` \w` ? A constant name should not have lowercase character. But `\w` is basicly `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: @AxelH I guess to make it less strict. But yea..  [A-Z0-9] sounds better.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following pattern/replace string in IntelliJ, it assumes the variables are properly named as constants, that is all uppercase.

Search string

```
private (String [A-Z_0-9$]* = .*;)
```

replace string

```
private static final $1
```

Comment: Isn't the regex wrong? I mean, can a variable start with a number?

Comment: Sure that could be changed but it's such a minor detail and if it started with a number there would be a syntax error anyway and I think we can assume the code is correct to start with.

Comment: @GeorgeZ. it is not supposed to recreate the logic of a compiler... I have a more important remark is `_1` should be a member or a constant ? And `$` is also a valid character

Comment: @AxelH I added the $ that was missing but I didn't understand the part about _1

Comment: Well, that's up to OP to answer that one, but a `_1` is a valid name for a variable. But there is no way to know for sure if this is suppose to be a constant or not since there are not letter ( so no upper/lower case).

Comment: @AxelH, Thanks now I understand what you meant. It feels like an extreme case, I would even say that OP has worse problems than making them static if the variables are named like that :)

Comment: I agree, just pointing the limit of this kind of logic. To be fair, I would treat the problem at the source and teach the dev that made that mess by replacing every variables by hand...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that worked from @kris's suggestion:

1. I copied all the fields needed refactoring to another dummy class with just these fields
2. I did a *Find->Replace* for all these fields from `private String` to `private static final String`

Comment: Good to know you made it! :-) . The answers posted are more generic for such situations. Probably its best to accept one of them!

Comment: Please accept one of the other answers that says this, to recognize their contribution. Its bad form to write your own answer that is essentially the same.